# How to make scrollable sidebar fixed in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, sass, tailwind-css, sidebar

I came across the BetterDev sidebar in which, if we add content to it, the sidebar also scrolls. Is there a way to make that sidebar fixed and not scrollable? I tried sticky, corrected with top-0 and left-0, but it didn't work.

- [Image when content is not there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1TwN.png)
- [Image when content is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L6Gr.png)

```html
    <div class="relative min-h-screen md:flex">
    
      <!-- mobile menu bar -->
      <div class="bg-gray-800 text-gray-100 flex justify-between md:hidden">
        <!-- logo -->
        <a href="#" class="block p-4 text-white font-bold">Better Dev</a>
    
        <!-- mobile menu button -->
        <button class="mobile-menu-button p-4 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700">
          <svg class="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    
      <!-- sidebar -->
      <div class="sidebar bg-blue-800 text-blue-100 w-64 space-y-6 py-7 px-2 absolute inset-y-0 left-0 transform -translate-x-full md:relative md:translate-x-0 transition duration-200 ease-in-out">
    
        <!-- logo -->
        <a href="#" class="text-white flex items-center space-x-2 px-4">
          <svg class="w-8 h-8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M9 12l2 2 4-4M7.835 4.697a3.42 3.42 0 001.946-.806 3.42 3.42 0 014.438 0 3.42 3.42 0 001.946.806 3.42 3.42 0 013.138 3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00.806 1.946 3.42 3.42 0 010 4.438 3.42 3.42 0 00-.806 1.946 3.42 3.42 0 01-3.138 3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00-1.946.806 3.42 3.42 0 01-4.438 0 3.42 3.42 0 00-1.946-.806 3.42 3.42 0 01-3.138-3.138 3.42 3.42 0 00-.806-1.946 3.42 3.42 0 010-4.438 3.42 3.42 0 00.806-1.946 3.42 3.42 0 013.138-3.138z" />
          </svg>
          <span class="text-2xl font-extrabold">Better Dev</span>
        </a>
    
        <!-- nav -->
        <nav>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
            Home
          </a>
          <a href="" class="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
            About
          </a>
          <a href="" class="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
            Features
          </a>
          <a href="" class="block py-2.5 px-4 rounded transition duration-200 hover:bg-blue-700 hover:text-white">
            Pricing
          </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    
      <!-- content -->
      <div class="flex-1 p-10 text-2xl font-bold">
        content goes here
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

How do I make the the navbar fixed after medium breakpoint and make the content scrollable when a lot content is added?

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/chris__sev/pen/RwKWXpJ)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this by making your content fill the screen height and then adding `overflow-y-auto` to the column that you want to have a scrollbar (if the content overflows).

For example, your container div could be:

```html
<div class="relative md:flex h-screen overflow-hidden">
```

And your content div could be:

```html
<div class="flex-1 p-10 text-2xl font-bold h-screen overflow-y-auto">
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/edlucas/pen/MWEVdjX)